# Why doesn't this jQuery slideshow work properly?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have inserted jquery slide show in to my newly created real estate web site.
My real estate web site runs on 'Openrealty' platform which is php.

Here is a part of my Original jquery code.

```
if(!repeat)
$this.parent()
.find('li:nth-child('+current+')  a')
.stop(true,true)
.animate({'marginRight':'-20px'},300,function(){
$(this).animate({'opacity':'0.7'},700);
});
```

When I look at where the error comes from through 'Firebug', it shows as follows.

```
if(!repeat)
$this.parent()
.find('li:nth-child('+current+') a')
.stop(true,true)
.animate(,300,function(){
$(this).animate(,700);
});
```

Here you can clearly see that some parts of the original code does not renders by the browser. Such as `{'marginRight':'-20px'}`

As shown by firebug the error begins from " .animate(,300,function(){ " onwards.

I need to find a solution why this Jquery not works in my web site.

Source of this Jquery slide show : http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/04/28/pretty-simple-content-slider-with-jquery-and-css3/

Any feedback is highly welcomed...

Thanks for the first 2 answers and request.
Yes I removed all (') marks within all styling as per the answers.
But still the error occurs as same above...

Total Jquery script have three parts.
1. Link to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
2. Link to outside JS file called 'jquery.easing.1.3.js'
3. Inline script
Following is the inline jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var current = 1;

                var iterate     = function(){
                    var i = parseInt(current+1);
                    var lis = $('#rotmenu').children('li').size();
                    if(i>lis) i = 1;
                    display($('#rotmenu li:nth-child('+i+')'));
                }
                display($('#rotmenu li:first'));
                var slidetime = setInterval(iterate,3000);

                $('#rotmenu li').bind('click',function(e){
                    clearTimeout(slidetime);
                    display($(this));
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

                function display(elem){
                    var $this   = elem;
                    var repeat  = false;
                    if(current == parseInt($this.index() + 1))
                        repeat = true;


                           /* slide in the current one */
                if(!repeat)
                  $this.parent()
                   .find('li:nth-child('+current+') a')
                   .stop(true,true)
                   .animate({marginRight:-20px},300,function(){
                   $(this).animate({opacity:0.7},700);
                });


                    current = parseInt($this.index() + 1);

                    var elem = $('a',$this);

                        elem.stop(true,true).animate({marginRight:0px,opacity:1.0},300);

                    var info_elem = elem.next();
                    $('#rot1 .heading').animate({left:-420px}, 500,'easeOutCirc',function(){
                        $('h1',$(this)).html(info_elem.find('.info_heading').html());
                        $(this).animate({left:0px},400,'easeInOutQuad');
                    });

                    $('#rot1 .description').animate({bottom:-270px},500,'easeOutCirc',function(){
                        $('p',$(this)).html(info_elem.find('.info_description').html());
                        $(this).animate({bottom:0px},400,'easeInOutQuad');
                    })
                    $('#rot1').prepend(
                    $('<img/>',{
                        style   :   'opacity:0',
                        className : 'bg'
                    }).load(
                    function(){
                        $(this).animate({opacity:1},600);
                        $('#rot1 img:first').next().animate({opacity:0},700,function(){
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    }
                ).attr('src','slide-images/'+info_elem.find('.info_image').html()).attr('width','950').attr('height','300')
                );
                }
            });
        </script>
```

And following is the html part which shows the slide show.

```
<div id="sliderbox">

            <div class="rotator">
                <ul id="rotmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="rot1">Luxury Life</a>
                        <div style="display:none;">
                            <div class="info_image">1.jpg</div>
                            <div class="info_heading">Best Homes for you</div>
                            <div class="info_description">
                 This is description... 
                                <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="rot2">Smiling Faces</a>
                        <div style="display:none;">
                            <div class="info_image">2.jpg</div>
                            <div class="info_heading">Do at our best</div>
                            <div class="info_description">
                 This is description... 

                                <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="rot3">Tradition</a>
                        <div style="display:none;">
                            <div class="info_image">3.jpg</div>
                            <div class="info_heading">We goes with tradition</div>
                            <div class="info_description">
                 This is description... 

                                <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="rot4">Lands for sale</a>
                        <div style="display:none;">
                            <div class="info_image">4.jpg</div>
                            <div class="info_heading">A best place to live in Kandy</div>
                            <div class="info_description">
                 This is description... 

                                <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="rot5">True Nature</a>
                        <div style="display:none;">
                            <div class="info_image">5.jpg</div>
                            <div class="info_heading">Brings you beauty in nature</div>
                            <div class="info_description">
                               This is description... 
                                <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div id="rot1">
                    <img src="" width="950" height="300" class="bg" alt=""/>
                    <div class="heading">
                        <h1></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p></p>

                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and following is the CSS:

```
.rotator{
    background-color:#222;
    width:950px;
    height:300px;
    margin:0px auto;
    position:relative;
    /*font-family:'Myriad Pro',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;*/
    font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    /* letter-spacing:-1px; */
    letter-spacing:1px;
    border:3px solid #f0f0f0;
    overflow:hidden;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #222;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #222;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #222;
}
img.bg{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
.rotator ul{
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    margin-top:6px;
    z-index:999999;
}
.rotator ul li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    width:260px;
}
.rotator ul li a{
    width:230px;
    float:right;
    clear:both;
    padding-left:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#222;
    margin:1px -20px 1px 0px;
    /*opacity:0.7;*/
    color:#f0f0f0;
    font-size:12px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-right:none;
    outline:none;
/*
    text-shadow:-1px 1px 1px #000;
*/
    -moz-border-radius:10px 0px 0px 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
}

/* .rotator ul li a:hover{
      text-shadow:0px 0px 2px #fff;
}
*/

.rotator .heading{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:500px;
}

.rotator .heading h1{
    text-shadow:-1px 1px 1px #555;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:36px;
    padding:20px;
}

.rotator .description{
    width:300px;
    height:15px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#222;
    -moz-border-radius:0px 10px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    /*opacity:0.7;*/
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}

.rotator .description p{
    /*text-shadow:-1px 1px 1px #000;*/
    text-transform:none;
    letter-spacing:normal;
    line-height:10px;
    font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
}

a.more{
    color:orange;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:10px;
}

a.more:hover{
    color:#fff;
}
```

I have analysed every of these scripts but couldn't identified any issues...
Please tell me how I can solve this.

Comment: Can you show some more of your 'original PHP code'? It looks a lot like javascript code instead to me. How are you outputting this code to the document? Can we see the lines around them?

Comment: Yes I have reedited the question with more details and please look back it.. Tnx..

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you original code.

```
if(!repeat)
$this.parent()
.find('li:nth-child('+current+')  a')
.stop(true,true)
.animate({marginRight:-20},300,function(){
$(this).animate({opacity:0.7},700);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question with a feedback to your answer. Please refer it..

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS properties for the animate() function seem wrong.

Experiment without the ' (single quote characters)

```
if(!repeat)
$this.parent()
.find('li:nth-child('+current+')  a')
.stop(true,true)
.animate({marginRight:'-20px'},300,function(){
$(this).animate({opacity:0.7},700);
});
```

As in the animate() examples [from the jquery webpage](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question with a feedback to your answer. Please refer it..

Comment: @hearth - Don't put `px` in `{marginRight:-20px}`. If you are putting `px` then enclose it in quotes like this `{marginRight:"-20px"}`